# Postgresql: Recursive query for undirected graph

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I want to traverse through an undirected graph via SQL in Postgresql.

I have one table which consists of all edges with starting points and end points (as ids).

```
edge_id | start_node | end_node
      1            4          5
      2            5          7
      3            1          5
```

This is what I tried so far. This works in some cases but travels directed trough the graph which leads to mistakes in some cases.

```
WITH RECURSIVE path AS 
(
    SELECT 
        edge_id, start_node, end_node
    FROM 
        simulation.edge_data
    WHERE 
        start_node = ANY ('{ 1,8}'::int[]) 
        OR end_node = ANY ('{ 1,8}'::int[])

    UNION

    SELECT 
        e.edge_id, e.start_node, e.end_node
    FROM 
        simulation.edge_data e, path s
    WHERE 
        s.start_node = e.start_node 
        OR s.start_node = e.end_node 
        OR s.end_node = e.end_node 
        OR s.end_node = e.start_node
)
SELECT * FROM path;
```

Output should be all edges that are connected to a starting point

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output.

Comment: Could you share your table's structure and some sample data? It would help us help you

Comment: What have You tried so far? What went wrong?

Comment: Added sample data. I tried a recursive querry. But this only travels directed trough the graph

Comment: Kindly elaborate your output.

Comment: How about this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b550/9

Comment: @RomanHocke Wow thanks! Now i guess it would be not too bad to get all the edges at the same time? How do i do that?

Comment: @ZynicM You can surround the original query with `SELECT * FROM edges WHERE ARRAY[xstart, xend] <@ ARRAY( ...original query... )` Or incorporate the edges ids into original query (I am too lazy for now :-) - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53969/4

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @ZynicM the first one destroys all the performance